# Python Webpage Downloader

Tags: python, html, sockets

Hey guys I need help with this please. I'm desperate.

Develop a webpage downloader program in Python using basic socket
programming, as discussed in the class. The program receives a URL pointing to the base HTML file
as a command line argument, and then downloads this base file as well as all image objects within that
file. You only need to support nonpersistent connections.
Recall that in all class projects, you must use basic socket programming for networking and not
higher-level libraries.
Hint: You can use the HTMLParser library to parse the HTML file and identify all images there. More
information about this library can be found at https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like 2 assignments. Certainly you don't expect that we heard what was "discussed in class!"

1. Use sockets to perform HTTP GETs
2. Parse HTML

Work on them independently.
Glue them together when done.